# OpenGL slow updates when objects are small in screen space

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine, x11, slowdown

I'm learning OpenGL with X11 on Linux, and got a problem that i don't realise what is wrong.

When i draw a object that covers a big space on the screen, it renders fast and updates to X11 with high framerate. But when i move camera far from the object, or draw a small object, in a way that it will cover small space on screen(say, in pixels area), it updates really slow. As small it draws, slower it updates the frame.

When i'm 100 units far from a 1x1 plane, it reaches around 1 Frame per second.

Here is the Code:

```
XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, win, &gwa);
glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
SetupViewMatrix();

Camera * cam = mainCamera.GetComponent<Camera>();
if(cam != NULL){
    CamPose(cam->eyePose, cam->pivotPoint, cam->upDirection);
} else {
    CamPose(Vector3::back(), Vector3::forward(), Vector3::up());
}
//glViewport(0, 0, gwa.width, gwa.height);

ClearScreen();

GLfloat cube[] = {
        -0.05f, -0.05f, -0.05f,
        -0.05f,  0.05f, -0.05f,
         0.05f,  0.05f, -0.05f,
        -0.05f, -0.05f, -0.05f,
         0.05f,  0.05f, -0.05f,
         0.05f, -0.05f, -0.05f,
};//*/
GLfloat colors[] = {
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,
};//*/

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, cube);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glXSwapBuffers(dpy, win);
glFlush();
```

and the SetupViewMatrix function:

```
void WindowDrawer::SetupViewMatrix(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(65, (float)Width/Height, 0.1, 1000);
};
```

and the ClearScreen function:

```
void WindowDrawer::ClearScreen(){
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

EDIT:
    I'm adding some more code to help.
    This one is the Init function i'm using to create a window:

```
void WindowDrawer::InitX11OpenGL(){
    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if(dpy == NULL){
        printf("\n\tCannot Connect to X server\n\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);

    vi = glXChooseVisual(dpy, 0, att);
    if(vi == NULL){
        printf("\n\tno appropriate visual found\n\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("\nvisual %p selected\n", (void *)vi->visualid);
    }
    cmap = XCreateColormap(dpy, root, vi->visual, AllocNone);
    swa.colormap = cmap;
    swa.event_mask = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask;

    win = XCreateWindow(dpy, root, 0, 0, 720, 480, 0, vi->depth, InputOutput, vi->visual, CWColormap | CWEventMask, &swa);
    XMapWindow(dpy, win);
    glc = glXCreateContext(dpy, vi, NULL, GL_TRUE);
    glXMakeCurrent(dpy, win, glc);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

And this one i'm using to create a event loop:

```
void WindowObject::DealWithEvents(){
    if(XEventsQueued(windowDrawer.dpy, QueuedAlready)){
        XNextEvent(windowDrawer.dpy, &xev);
        eventHandler.RouteXEvents(&xev, windowDrawer.dpy);
    } else {
        memset(&redrawEvent, 0, sizeof(redrawEvent));
        redrawEvent.type = Expose;
        redrawEvent.xexpose.window = windowDrawer.win;
        XSendEvent(windowDrawer.dpy, windowDrawer.win, False, ExposureMask, &redrawEvent);
        XFlush(windowDrawer.dpy);
        eventHandler.RouteXEvents((XEvent *)&redrawEvent, windowDrawer.dpy);
    }
};
```

Well, as i can see, this seens to be not a performance issue, but a updating queue (or something like) issue. Cause when the object is close to the camera, say, it uses a large screen space, it draws faster like it should, but when it gets smaller in screen space, it linearly slows down screen updates. I'm printing the events for expose, keypress and keyrelease, all these event runs fast, like it should, only the screen area updates doesn't follow the system's speed.

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you targeting? For modern OpenGL, `glEnableClientState` was removed in OpenGL 4.5., and rendering without a shader is not supported, either.

Comment: I am sure that is not the problem in the question.

Comment: How are you measuring the frame rate? (I hope not just by looking at it, small objects often don't change) How are you generating the X Expose event to force a redraw, XClear after each frame, a timer? Do you have event compression turned on?

Comment: I don't know what version it is, just included GL/gl.h GL/glx.h and GL/glu.h.

Comment: I'm following tutorials...

I'm not measuring framerate, but when i print to console, the draw functions are called normally, many times by second, only the window that isn't updated in the same time.
I didn't configure any event compression and i'm not sending XExpose redraw event, i'll try that now...

Comment: You should show more code which is executed in the render loop.From what we see here there should be no apparent performance degradation over time.In fact,it should be the opposite (that's the less fragments cover the screen,the faster the rasterization goes).Maybe you run into memory leaks somewhere.And you don't have to flush the pipeline after swapping the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i found the error, and i'm aswering my own question for this. I'm ashamed to tell this, cause it was so stupid as expected by a really newbie in graphics :/

The problem is that i'm working with a small screen, on a low ppi monitor. Additionally, the shape on screen is a perfect square (it doesn't paints diagonal edges on pixels), so when the object is small, it takes a long time till repaint the border pixels. Computer graphics uses some antialiasing effect to smooth this effect, and raw opengl doesn't, so it cause a really different effect from what i'm used to see. I took a long time till realise that was only a pixel detail issue...

Thank you all for any help.

Comment: This doesn't explain the illogical 1 fps.

Comment: Well, there was no 1 fps, but just the pixels took around 1 second to be repainted because of the small shape being drawn, say, the interpolation between pixels only change the pixels to be drawn at 1 second...

Answer (score -2):

Theres some stuff in here that doesn't look like its "optimized" correctly. For example, you use gluPerspective. Thats been deprecated for 10 years!! We don't want that! Why not just make your own viewmatrix in your camera class? :)

Also, I'm not sure if this is the problem. But it seems you're calling glClearColor inside of the RENDER loop. Which is of course, not good. Put that in your init function. Thats possible its the problem.

Comment: Thank you by reply. I'm just following tutorials, this is why i'm using old functions :). I tried to move glClearColor to init function, but this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Also, later i'll try to implement new better methods, but for now i'm just learning :)

Comment: @Verideth I give you one tip on SO. Don't post incomplete answers, people will downvote them straight.

Comment: @Verideth you are wrong on both parts.glClearColor should, and on some platforms (like tiled ones), is even strongly recommended to be called on each frame! And there is nothing wrong,performance wise,to use gluPerspective,even though it is deprecated functionality in the modern OpenGL. Please check carefully your knowledge of the subject which you are trying to answer to.